# eslint does not automatically fix on --fix

Tags: eslint

I use eslint to lint, but it does not automatically fix although I use --fix

```
PS C:\Users\issac\IdeaProjects\discord-bot> eslint --fix --ext .ts src
Warning: React version was set to "detect" in eslint-plugin-react settings, but the "react" package is not installed. Assuming latest React version for linting.

C:\Users\issac\IdeaProjects\discord-bot\src\bot.ts
  16:1  error    Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2   indent
  17:1  error    Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 4   indent
  18:1  error    Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 6  indent
  19:1  error    Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 8  indent
... all most errors indent
  75:1   error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 6             indent
  76:1   error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 6             indent
  76:34  error  Unexpected use of '<<'                                    no-bitwise
  77:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 4              indent

✖ 862 problems (852 errors, 10 warnings)
  790 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

Although I run with --fix every time, those errors won't disappear.
This is my .eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        es2021: true,
        node: true,
    },
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    plugins: [
        '@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    extends: [
        'airbnb',
        'airbnb-typescript'
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 13,
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    rules: {
        'max-len': [1, 150, 4],
        'object-curly-spacing': [2, 'always'],
        'require-jsdoc': [0],
        'indent': [2, 4],
        'linebreak-style': [0],
        'keyword-spacing': [2],
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts"],
            rules: {
                "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error"]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Is there any way to make eslint fix those all indents?

Comment: Did you save your files first?

Comment: Start by trying to lint one file. And don't use the save all. use CTRL+S, and make sure you click into the file so you target it.

Comment: It was my problem, the custom settings were the problem going over the airbnb config

Comment: In my case it was that prettier and linter run in parallel, causing prettier to put old content back to files.